# image not showing on server in codeigniter site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have uploaded my site in demo folder on server, which I develop in codeigniter. Everything is working fine , but problem is unable to access "uploaded_files" folder so image is not showing on site.

This is the my htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /demo/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I am not able to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that whether 'uploaded_files' folder is outside demo or not. 
Now on the view page try to inspect the image source via F12 and see if the image path appears to be a valid path. If 'uploaded_files' is outside demo folder then set your image absolute path/relative path respectively.